# What materials are most transparent to magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnets

What common materials are most transparent to magnetic fields?  I have two applications; in each case I want minimal distortion and degradation of the magnetic field:

1. Wrapping/surrounding a magnet (permanent or electro-) to protect it; and
2. Wrapping a hollow tube with windings to make an air-core electromagnet.

I'm not a physicist and I'm not versed in the jargon, but I *think* I'm looking for low permittivity.

I've found sources for magnetic shielding material, but this is sort of the opposite.

Comment: Permitivity is for electric fields. I believe you mean permeability. Wood, plastic, paper.

Comment: If it's a solenoid shape, even more so if it is used with a core, there will be negligible difference from the wrapping material around the "cylinder" part of it, if it is very thin.